# Why use 流されていく in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

This is a sentence from Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, from the scene towards the beginning where Harry and Ron are flying the car and are just approaching Hogwarts.

> 車は湖のほうに流されていき、ハリーは思わず座席の端をしっかり握りしめた。

Which I would translate as:

> As the car drifted towards the lake, harry instinctively gripped the edge of his seat.

Why is 流されて(which I assume is passive of 流す) used here, instead of just 流れて?

Comment: Hmmm... because the author wanted to use a passive voice for the first part?

Comment: @macraf thank you for your incredibly enlightening insight.

Comment: Why is the Japanese translation of Harry Potter so popular around here? I even know someone IRL who spent hours pouring over translated Roling.

Comment: Isn't it just because the author wanted to put emphasis on the fact the the car is being moved through the air (as opposed to moving by its own power)? Never read HP, but I guess someone is using magic to move the car?

Comment: @FlorianBaierl hmm, it could be. As in the car is flown, rathern then flying by itself. I guess that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Ragaroni, because people like and know Harry Potter already, so they are curious what the translated version is like? It's not all that surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having read any Harry Potter myself:

It is probably because the author wants to put an emphasis on the fact the the car is being moved/flown through the air by an external power (magic?) as opposed to moving by its own.